# How can I use OIDC through a custom URL in Blazor Webassembly published on Azure App Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to deploy a Blazor WASM solution using both local, Google and Microsoft signin, but am having trouble when using a custom URL.

I've deployed to Azure App Service, and following previous threads, have got it working through the URL MySite.azurewebsites.net by ammending the service-worker.published.js to:

```
async function onFetch(event) {
    let cachedResponse = null;
    if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
        // For all navigation requests, try to serve index.html from cache
        // If you need some URLs to be server-rendered, edit the following check to exclude those URLs
        const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate'
            && !event.request.url.includes('/connect/')
            && !event.request.url.includes('/signin-google')
            && !event.request.url.includes('/Identity/');

        const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);
    }

    return cachedResponse || fetch(event.request);
}
```

My problem now is that I've added a custom https domain of MySite.co.uk, the site still works fine when I go to MySite.azurewebsites.net, but when I go to MySite.co.uk it sends me to the "Sorry, there's nothing at this address" page.

Any suggestions of how to get this all wired up to allow use of the custom domain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was something to do with the javascript libraries used on the login page. Once I resolved all of the errors in the javascript console, it started working, so not sure exactly which one fixed it.